# Docker image from customized Grafana source code

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, grafana

We have fork from the Grafana source and make changes mainly the UI. Now, I want to create docker image and faced issue. The Dockerfile in the root of the branch that we use:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG BASE_IMAGE=alpine:3.17
ARG JS_IMAGE=node:18-alpine3.17
ARG JS_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
ARG GO_IMAGE=golang:1.20.6-alpine3.17

ARG GO_SRC=go-builder
ARG JS_SRC=js-builder

FROM --platform=${JS_PLATFORM} ${JS_IMAGE} as js-builder

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8000

WORKDIR /tmp/grafana

COPY package.json yarn.lock .yarnrc.yml ./
COPY .yarn .yarn
COPY packages packages
COPY plugins-bundled plugins-bundled

RUN yarn install --immutable

COPY tsconfig.json .eslintrc .editorconfig .browserslistrc .prettierrc.js babel.config.json .linguirc ./
COPY public public
COPY scripts scripts
COPY emails emails

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN yarn build

FROM ${GO_IMAGE} as go-builder

ARG COMMIT_SHA=""
ARG BUILD_BRANCH=""
ARG GO_BUILD_TAGS="oss"
ARG WIRE_TAGS="oss"
ARG BINGO="true"

# Install build dependencies
RUN if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
      apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make git; \
    fi

WORKDIR /tmp/grafana

COPY go.* ./
COPY .bingo .bingo

RUN go mod download
RUN if [[ "$BINGO" = "true" ]]; then \
      go install github.com/bwplotka/bingo@latest && \
      bingo get -v; \
    fi

COPY embed.go Makefile build.go package.json ./
COPY cue.mod cue.mod
COPY kinds kinds
COPY local local
COPY packages/grafana-schema packages/grafana-schema
COPY public/app/plugins public/app/plugins
COPY public/api-merged.json public/api-merged.json
COPY pkg pkg
COPY scripts scripts
COPY conf conf
COPY .github .github
COPY LICENSE ./

ENV COMMIT_SHA=${COMMIT_SHA}
ENV BUILD_BRANCH=${BUILD_BRANCH}

RUN make build-go GO_BUILD_TAGS=${GO_BUILD_TAGS} WIRE_TAGS=${WIRE_TAGS}

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as tgz-builder

WORKDIR /tmp/grafana

ARG GRAFANA_TGZ="grafana-latest.linux-x64-musl.tar.gz"

COPY ${GRAFANA_TGZ} /tmp/grafana.tar.gz

# add -v to make tar print every file it extracts
RUN tar x -z -f /tmp/grafana.tar.gz --strip-components=1

# helpers for COPY --from
FROM ${GO_SRC} as go-src
FROM ${JS_SRC} as js-src

# Final stage
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

LABEL maintainer="Grafana Labs <hello@grafana.com>"

ARG GF_UID="472"
ARG GF_GID="0"

ENV PATH="/usr/share/grafana/bin:$PATH" \
    GF_PATHS_CONFIG="/etc/grafana/grafana.ini" \
    GF_PATHS_DATA="/var/lib/grafana" \
    GF_PATHS_HOME="/usr/share/grafana" \
    GF_PATHS_LOGS="/var/log/grafana" \
    GF_PATHS_PLUGINS="/var/lib/grafana/plugins" \
    GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING="/etc/grafana/provisioning"

WORKDIR $GF_PATHS_HOME

# Install dependencies
RUN if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
      apk add --no-cache ca-certificates bash curl tzdata musl-utils && \
      apk info -vv | sort; \
    elif grep -i -q ubuntu /etc/issue; then \
      DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
      apt-get update && \
      apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl tzdata musl && \
      apt-get autoremove -y && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    else \
      echo 'ERROR: Unsupported base image' && /bin/false; \
    fi

# glibc support for alpine x86_64 only
RUN if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue && [ `arch` = "x86_64" ]; then \
      wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
      wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.35-r0/glibc-2.35-r0.apk \
        -O /tmp/glibc-2.35-r0.apk && \
      wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.35-r0/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk \
        -O /tmp/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk && \
      apk add --force-overwrite --no-cache /tmp/glibc-2.35-r0.apk /tmp/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk && \
      rm -f /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
      ln -s /usr/glibc-compat/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
      rm -f /tmp/glibc-2.35-r0.apk && \
      rm -f /tmp/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk && \
      rm -f /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
      rm -f /etc/ld.so.cache; \
    fi

COPY --from=go-src /tmp/grafana/conf ./conf

RUN if [ ! $(getent group "$GF_GID") ]; then \
      if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
        addgroup -S -g $GF_GID grafana; \
      else \
        addgroup --system --gid $GF_GID grafana; \
      fi; \
    fi && \
    GF_GID_NAME=$(getent group $GF_GID | cut -d':' -f1) && \
    mkdir -p "$GF_PATHS_HOME/.aws" && \
    if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
      adduser -S -u $GF_UID -G "$GF_GID_NAME" grafana; \
    else \
      adduser --system --uid $GF_UID --ingroup "$GF_GID_NAME" grafana; \
    fi && \
    mkdir -p "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/datasources" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/dashboards" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/notifiers" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/plugins" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/access-control" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/alerting" \
             "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" \
             "$GF_PATHS_DATA" && \
    cp conf/sample.ini "$GF_PATHS_CONFIG" && \
    cp conf/ldap.toml /etc/grafana/ldap.toml && \
    chown -R "grafana:$GF_GID_NAME" "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_HOME/.aws" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING" && \
    chmod -R 777 "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_HOME/.aws" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING"

COPY --from=go-src /tmp/grafana/bin/grafana* /tmp/grafana/bin/*/grafana* ./bin/
COPY --from=js-src /tmp/grafana/public ./public
COPY --from=go-src /tmp/grafana/LICENSE ./

EXPOSE 3000

ARG RUN_SH=./packaging/docker/run.sh

COPY ${RUN_SH} /run.sh

USER "$GF_UID"
ENTRYPOINT [ "/run.sh" ]
```

I'm in Apple silicon and faced error to build the image. But, when I comment out the the below code the dashboard is fine.

```
RUN if [[ "$BINGO" = "true" ]]; then \
      go install github.com/bwplotka/bingo@latest && \
      bingo get -v; \
    fi
```

My questions:

1. What does this code do?
2. The final deployment will be in the Linux server so do we need is code in Linux environment?

Thanks.

I tried to build the image and encountered with error. Now, if I remove certain peice of code, I was manage to build the image. My quesion is do I need that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RUN if [[ "$BINGO" = "true" ]]; then \
   go install github.com/bwplotka/bingo@latest && \
   bingo get -v; \
fi
```

This part of the code is for installing bingo.

Comment out this part of the code does not affect it, as it has already copied the local bingo in the previous code section `COPY .bingo .bingo`. The commented out part only performed a bingo version update operation.

Why did you meet error, I think the reason is that go version set in dockerfile does not matched the latest version of bingo.

So, I check grafana's latest github repository, golang:1.21.6-alpine3.18 is the latest setting in dockerfile. Or You can make the following change and try again.

```
ARG GO_IMAGE=golang:1.21.6-alpine3.18
```

Comment: This is from the branch release-10.1.1, and it only works if I comment out the BINGO part in Apple silicon. So, you are saying, that if we comment out this part no affect at all?